# Passing/emitting events through to parent component?

Tags: angular, angular-components

In Angular I can create a child component that emits an action:

```
@Component({
   ...
    template: `
      <button (click)='someAction($event)'>Click Me</button>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {

    @Output() onChildAction = new EventEmitter();

    childAction() {
      this.onChildAction.emit();
    }
}
```

and a parent component to handle it. Something like:

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
      <child-component (onChildAction)="parentAction()"></child-component>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {
    parentAction() {
      console.log('Hello');
    }
}
```

This works fine, but is there a way to "passthrough" the action directly to the parent without having to create a click handler in the child that calls `.emit()`?

Something like:

```
@Component({
   ...
    template: `
      <button (click)='onChildAction.emit($event)'>Click Me</button>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Output() onChildAction = new EventEmitter();
}
```

and:

```
@Component({
    ...
    template: `
      <child-component (onChildAction)="parentAction()"></child-component>
    `
})
export class ParentComponent {
    parentAction() {
      console.log('Hello');
    }
}
```

where the event is immediately emitted to the parent without having to go through a child handler. This is useful when you have simply click events in the child that you want to let the parent component handle.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: You could also consider [using a service for this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: @bugs I had tried this and it didn't seem to work. Let me try again

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony here's a quick [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wssqjh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to emit events from the template file. In fact I do the same when it is a single line code. This is easy to read as well.

`<button (click)='onChildAction.emit($event)'>Click Me</button>`

Here is a [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmeklt)

Comment: I'm not sure why it wasn't working for me before, but a reload and everything works. Thanks